# Changing WordPress Sticky Class Name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, zurb-foundation

Unfortunately, Foundation and WordPress both use the "sticky" class. To avoid that, I've always used a little function that changes the class to 'wp-sticky' for WordPress. However, that function now seems to be applying that class to every post (including non-sticky posts).

```
function remove_sticky_class($classes) {
    $classes = array_diff($classes, array("sticky"));
    $classes[] = 'wp-sticky';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class','remove_sticky_class');
```

Any ideas on how I can change just the sticky class name (and not have it apply to all posts)?

Edit: It does REPLACE 'sticky' with 'wp-sticky' on sticky posts, however, it also ADDS it to posts that are not sticky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably never worked like it was supposed to in the first place. The problem was there was no conditional in place to check if `'sticky'` was in the `$classes` array before adding `'wp-sticky'` to the array.

```php
function remove_sticky_class( $classes ) {
    if ( in_array( 'sticky', $classes, true ) ) {
        $classes = array_diff($classes, array('sticky'));
        $classes[] = 'wp-sticky';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'remove_sticky_class' );
```